# bizday() not flagging June 20, 2022 (Juneteenth) as NYSE market holiday R

Tags: r, bizdays

How can I add a missing date when a market was closed to a loaded calendar so I can use the date difference function bizdays() from library(bizdays)?

From NYSE's website:

> Juneteenth National Independence Day  Monday, June 20, 2022 (Juneteenth
> holiday observed)

But bizday() doesn't recognize 2022-06-20 as a NYSE market holiday

```
> library(bizdays)
> load_rmetrics_calendars(2000:2022)
Calendar Rmetrics/NYSE loaded

> bizdays.options$set(default.calendar = "Rmetrics/NYSE")
> is.bizday("2022-06-20")
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version 4021.106 of the package timeDate with publication date 2022-9-29 resolved the issue and now recognizes 2022-06-20 as a market holiday for the NYSE:

```
> library(timeDate)
> library(bizdays)
> load_rmetrics_calendars(2000:2023)
Calendar Rmetrics/NYSE loaded
> bizdays.options$set(default.calendar = "Rmetrics/NYSE")
> is.bizday("2022-06-20")
[1] FALSE
```

For background, I previously encountered the issue with not flagging Juneteenth as a market holiday, because I was using the package timeDate dated 2018-02-21, and Juneteenth was not established as a US national holiday until 2021-06-18.